# How do I open a used notification in Android?

Tags: applications, notifications, notification-bar, push-notifications

Does it have someway to "re-use" the push notifications? I know that exists a way to create a shortcut to only view the used and past notifications. I want something that gives me the oportunity to use again some notification that was gone.

Example:

I have some Instagram Notification:

Fulano liked your photo.(When I touch in this notification, Instagram opens directly in that pho)

So that notification disapear.

I want to see again this notification and I can touch again and see the photo from instagram.

Someone know some application about it?

Comment: There may be a fix using the xposed framework, as long as you are on <lollipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an Android developer and I can tell you that exactly like what you want it doesn't exist because at development time we set how they should work. Platform asks us what to do when we click them, if they should be persistent or not, etc. So what you want is impossible because every developer should then add this feature.

Something possible would be an app with reading notifications permission enabled that look and save any notification on the device and listen for changes in them. And when it detects that the app is gone and only was "used" once, then it shows up again. This app won't function exactly equal as the original one because the original notification comes with data that only the app and Android knows. It could open the app at its best.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a notification back in your notification list natively, but there is a native settings shortcut to let you see your notification history. **New shortcut > Settings shortcut > Notifications**